# Cypress window does not respond when I pick a browser

Tags: cypress

When I run my test with command `npx cypress open`, the cypress window opens.

I pick E2E testing. Then next step is to pick a browser.
But Cypress window is frozen.

[image: frozen cypress window]

#### What I tried

- I try to pick every browser offered (Chrome, Edge, Electron).
- I try run the test with command `cypress run` but after a minute I got a timeout error because the browser doesn't respond.
- I saw some missing cache in terminal so this might be a problem. But I don't know what it means.
- I try to upgrade cypress, but it doesn't help.

Does someone has the same problem or knows a solution ?

Comment: What OS are you running Cypress? Did you check the [troubleshooting page](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/troubleshooting), see the logs or start with `--browser` option to specify a browser available on you system directly?